# Bitwise Column vs. Separate Table

Tags: sql, relational-database

I would like to get some input on pros and cons of storing a bitwise enumeration in a table as opposed to creating a separate table.

To elaborate, suppose I'm storing information about various applications, and each one can use various programming languages.

Approach 1. Typically, I would create three tables:

```
**APP**
APP_ID
APP_NAME

**LANGUAGE**
LANGUAGE_ID
LANGUAGE_NAME

**APP_LANGUAGE**
APP_ID
LANGUAGE_ID
```

Approach 2. Another approach that I can think of is to assign languages to a bitwise enumeraion and store a single integer in the APP table:

```
**APP**
APP_ID
APP_NAME
LANGUAGES

**LANGUAGE**
LANGUAGE_ID | LANGUAGE_NAME | LANGUAGE_VALUE
------------+---------------+---------------
1           |  Java         |      1
2           |  Python       |      2
3           |  Ruby         |      4
4           |  C#           |      8
etc.
```

Obviously, APP table will not be tied to LANGUAGE by a foreign key in this case.

What are the fundamental differences between these two approaches? I assume the first approach requires more processing on the database side, especially if languages can be added or removed from an app, while the second will probably require more processing in the code. What about performance, indexing, running reports where user can filter the results by one or more languages, etc.?

I understand that if I had to store additional attributes for each app/language pair (such as % composition of each language within an app), the first approach would be a no brainer, and so the question would not be applicable in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first method is the "right" method for storing this information in a relational database.  The "right" method has several advantages.  I can readily think of the following:

- Queries on the language can make use of indexes.
- Adding a new language is trivial.
- Assigning a new language to an app is simple:  just inserting a new row rather than a bunch of bit fiddling.
- You can track when a new language is assigned (by having a `CreatedAt` column).
- You don't have to think about what to do when you need to support more than 8/32/64 or whatever bits/languages.

Basically, bit fiddling does not help in relational databases (for the most part).  SQL engines often do not provide very good operations for bits.  And, the expense of an update/insert is typically the logging and the I/O, not the setting of bits.

The underlying data structures in SQL are centered around data pages, not individual registers/local cache memory.  Intuition about what works well in a language such as C/C++ may not help in an environment centered on big (or at least large'ish) data and parallel processing.  A key performance goal in SQL is typically to reduce the number of disk reads, not hyper-optimization of local memory.

Comment: Well, it's a well thought-out opinion, and that's what I asked for, so I'll happily accept it as an answer :)